# what are the paramteres in asynctask in this case?

Tags: android, ssh, android-asynctask

I'm new to AsyncTask and this is the first time I use it. What i am trying to achieve is the following:
I would like to have an activity which has a button and a textview. When I press the button the app makes an ssh connection in the background and it connects to my raspberry pi. It runs a couple of python scripts and uploads them to dropbox.

When it's ready, the textview warns me that I can find my file in dropbox, as the upload was complete. If I'm right, I shouldn't write anything in the AsyncTask parameter list or should I?

Aside from the argument list, are there more to do on my code?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class Aszin extends AppCompatActivity {

String cmd = "python /home/pi/Desktop/get_db_pic.py";
private static String USERNAME = "piro"; // username for remote host
private static String PASSWORD = "password"; // password of the remote host
private static String host  = "192.168.xx.xx"; // remote host address
private static int port = 22;

TextView tv1;
Button btn_ssh;
private AsyncTask<String, Integer, ???> asyncTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aszin);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.setText("default");

    btn_ssh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn_ssh .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            connect2pi(cmd);
        }
    });

}

public void connect2pi(final String cmd){
    asyncTask = new AsyncTask<String, Integer, ??>() {

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground() {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                JSch jsch = new JSch();
                Session session = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, host, port);

                session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setPassword(PASSWORD);

                session.connect();

                ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

                InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();

                channelExec.setCommand(cmd);
                channelExec.connect();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.add(line);

                }
                channelExec.getExitStatus();

                channelExec.disconnect();

                session.disconnect();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + e);
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            tv1.setText("your file has been downloaded");
            btn_ssh.setEnabled(true);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            tv1.setText("your file is getting downloaded");
            btn_ssh.setEnabled(false);

        }

    };
    asyncTask.execute(cmd);

}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29559386/6950238) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters for `AsyncTask` are the following:

```
  AsyncTask<doInBackgroundParams, onProgressUpdateParams, onPostExecuteParams>
```

In your case you are not not using `onProgressUpdate` and `doInBackground` so you can leave it as `Void`. You are filling an `ArrayList<String> result` in `doInBackground` and probably want to use the values in `onPostExecute` so the value would be `ArrayList<String>`. If not leave it as `Void`.
In the end it looks like this

```
 asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, host, port);

            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword(PASSWORD);

            session.connect();

            ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

            InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();

            channelExec.setCommand(cmd);
            channelExec.connect();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.add(line);

            }
            channelExec.getExitStatus();

            channelExec.disconnect();

            session.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        tv1.setText("your file has been downloaded");
        btn_ssh.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        tv1.setText("your file is getting downloaded");
        btn_ssh.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

[See the docs here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. was it intentional, that you didn't insert the     asyncTask.execute(cmd); line? Because I get errors because of this.

Comment: @johnnycigar It's only the code for the async parameters. You can add that of course.

Comment: Okay, done, the last error: missing return statement from doinBackground (line 87 <-- https://pastebin.com/s21bznRT) I wrote return null but the code doesn't do anything. Could you help? Thanks!

Comment: As I said you are not doing anything with `List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();` in your code. You might want to return that. See my first point about that in my answer.